# how to fix font-size scale by responsive media?

Tags: html, css

How to fix font-size scale by responsive media?
I don't want text scale to small when responsive and I have a problem with chrome browser and Firefox work fine.
this this picture for chrome

[image: Issue on Chrome]

This is my Firefox browser

[image: Working fine on Firefox]

Comment: Do you have an image on both browser for comparison? & also please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you doing anything to set `font-size` ? Can you post your code?

Comment: i think you need to try css media queries https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_mediaqueries_fontsize

Comment: i use this font-family: Arial; and font-size 14px it just not normal table but i don't why it not working with chrome,  i added image so you can see.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

I think this is meta tag issues

Please read [Responsive Web Design - The Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)